# Is an SD card inserted into Nintendo 3DS also region-locked?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, region-lock

After [I found out about the region-lock on the Nintendo 3DS](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291480/can-i-play-pok%C3%A9mon-sun-and-moon-purchased-in-another-country), I wondered if an SD card that the 3DS uses to save the game data on is *also* region-locked.

For example, can you use an SD card that is purchased in Italy in a 3DS that is purchased in Japan? Or can the SD card be used only in the same region as 3DS?

I don't believe it is also region-locked, but would like to know definitively before I buy a new SD card.

Comment: @Vemonus Thank you for the edit. Why is the article of the SD card "an", not "a"?

Comment: haha, sorry, I'm a bit of a grammar Nazi. The reason you'd use "an" instead of "a" is because you would say it like "Ess Dee". While SD starts with a consonant, which normally means you'd use "a" as the correct article, acronyms break this rule since you are pronouncing the letter itself, which gives a vowel sound in the beginning of some letters, like F, H, L, M, N, R, S, or X.

Comment: @Vemonus Ahhhh I knew about the rule but have never cared about the pronunciation of "SD". It is what I learned in HS, using a classic example of "an hour". Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SD cards do not have any sort of regions to them so you are free to buy a SD card from anywhere. The only type of products that are ever regionlocked are:

- **Disks, DVDs, Videogames, etc**
- **Software**
- **Websites**

Do make sure though that when you buy an SD card that it is compatible with your 3Ds. Nintendo luckily has a page that shows [what SD cards have been tested to work properly with the 3DS](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/274/~/what-sd-cards-and-microsd-cards-are-compatible%3F).

Comment: The only thing that might create a problem is if you expect your game saves to transfer from a 3ds to another using a SD card. Not a 100% sure of how it would interact but I suspect that it might cause conflicts.

Comment: It is possible to have some sort of conflict like that but SD cards are hot swappable so they should not have too many problems with it. The only real problems would come if you tried to use an incompatible SD card switching between two different types of 3DS

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any sources to back your answer up? It would be more helpful if you have.

Comment: The only real source I have for this is a reddit thread that is a big [QA for SD Cards](https://www.reddit.com/r/3DS/comments/1jnhfy/since_we_keep_getting_sd_card_questions_ill_make/)